# Button press not returning Line2D object in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm working with matplotlib and tkinter to create a program which can plot graphs using matplotlib and we can interact with graphs using buttons (created using Tkinter) .I have a button named 'Line' which manipulates the behaviour of the Line2D object already created by matplotlib. But I cannot call the Line2D object by using the `command=` keyword argument of the button widget.

A very simple working example is:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

squares = [i**2 for i in range(-10, 10)]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

line1 = ax.plot(squares)
print(eval('line1'))
plt.show()
```

The output of the print command `print(eval('line1'))` is as predicted:

```
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x000002BF273FEF48>]
```

But in the same manner if I use the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frameA = Frame(master)

        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frameA)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

        line1 = ax.plot(squares)
        plt.show()

        frameB = Frame(master)
        buttonA = Button(frameB, text="line1", height=20, width=50, command=lambda: print(eval(buttonA.cget('text'))))

        buttonA.pack(side="top")

        frameA.grid(row=0, column=0)
        frameB.grid(row=0, column=1)


squares = [i**2 for i in range(-10,10)]

root = Tk()
MyApp = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

The `command=lambda: print(eval(buttonA.cget('text')))` portion instead of returning a Line2D object generates an error.
I am using `print()` function for simplicity sake so once I can successfully call the Line2D object, I can manipulate its attributes using button.

Comment: Why did you write `eval('line1')` instead of just `line1`?  Your code has absolutely no need of `eval()`.

Comment: @jasonharper I am going to make a dozen other buttons (using for loops) and each button will be connected to its own corresponding plot. The only connection I see is setting text value of button to the name of the plot, and thus calling the plot through eval function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand in which context the lambda function is evaluated. In this context, `line1` doesn't exist as variable any more.

Here is an option:

```
from tkinter import *
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):

        frameA = Frame(master)

        fig = Figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=frameA)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='top', fill='both', expand=1)

        self.line1 = ax.plot(squares)

        frameB = Frame(master)
        self.buttonA = Button(frameB, text="self.line1", height=20, width=50, 
                         command=self.func)

        self.buttonA.pack(side="top")

        frameA.grid(row=0, column=0)
        frameB.grid(row=0, column=1)

    def func(self):
        print(eval(self.buttonA.cget('text')))


squares = [i**2 for i in range(-10,10)]

root = Tk()
MyApp = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Please consider not using `eval` though. It's awkward style. Instead you could use a dictionary that maps strings to objects if that is needed.